# How to divide a value by the same value in the previous year in R? (Return calculation)

Tags: r, for-loop, return, finance, panel-data

I have a panel data set with approx 4000 companies over 13 years. I want to calculate the return on these companies through the formula below. The Price (P) I'm using is the firm's Closing Price, adjusted.

rt = ( P(t=1)/ P(t= t-1) ) - 1

I want to create a new column for this return. Does anybody have any experience with how to divide a value (in this case the closing price (P)), on the closing price the year before for all the companies without making it too complicated?

Thank you.

Comment: please provide adequate sample data.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a minimal reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example so that we are able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to work with commands and/or data structures which are aware of the panel structure of your data. One way is to use package `plm` and its `pdata.frame` data structure. Then you can easily compute lagged values and calculate returns per firm.

See the example below and let's assume the contained data set `Grunfeld` and its column `value` is the the Closing Price P you want to compute the return for as per your formula (`ret` in the example below).

You see that the function `lag` in package `plm` respects the panel structure of the data when looking at the output.

```
library(plm)
data("Grunfeld", package = "plm")

# print some lines to get an idea about the data
# first 3 lines for first 3 individuals
selected.obs <- c(1:3, 21:23, 41:43)
Grunfeld[selected.obs, ]
#>    firm year   inv  value capital
#> 1     1 1935 317.6 3078.5     2.8
#> 2     1 1936 391.8 4661.7    52.6
#> 3     1 1937 410.6 5387.1   156.9
#> 21    2 1935 209.9 1362.4    53.8
#> 22    2 1936 355.3 1807.1    50.5
#> 23    2 1937 469.9 2676.3   118.1
#> 41    3 1935  33.1 1170.6    97.8
#> 42    3 1936  45.0 2015.8   104.4
#> 43    3 1937  77.2 2803.3   118.0

# make data a pdata.frame (panel-aware data frame)
pGrun <- pdata.frame(Grunfeld, index = c("firm", "year"))

# compute lag
pGrun$lvalue <- plm::lag(pGrun$value)

# compute return as per formula:
pGrun$ret <- (pGrun$value / pGrun$lvalue) - 1

# print first 3 lines for first 3 individuals
pGrun[selected.obs, ]
#>        firm year   inv  value capital lvalue       ret
#> 1-1935    1 1935 317.6 3078.5     2.8     NA        NA
#> 1-1936    1 1936 391.8 4661.7    52.6 3078.5 0.5142764
#> 1-1937    1 1937 410.6 5387.1   156.9 4661.7 0.1556085
#> 2-1935    2 1935 209.9 1362.4    53.8     NA        NA
#> 2-1936    2 1936 355.3 1807.1    50.5 1362.4 0.3264093
#> 2-1937    2 1937 469.9 2676.3   118.1 1807.1 0.4809916
#> 3-1935    3 1935  33.1 1170.6    97.8     NA        NA
#> 3-1936    3 1936  45.0 2015.8   104.4 1170.6 0.7220229
#> 3-1937    3 1937  77.2 2803.3   118.0 2015.8 0.3906638
```